# How to make a highchart's Tree Map chart fill the entire page without overflowing

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

HighChart's Tree Map series works like a charm when it comes to fill the entire page width with a fixed height: as you resize the page, the tree map will resize horizontally accordingly.

On the other hand, if you try to make the height a percentage then resizing breaks completely. I was not able to make a tree map chart which fills the entire page horizontally and vertically. I really think I'm missing something!

I've made a fiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/gqeLfxy3/

Setting body and the chart's container height and width to 100% didn't help.

```
body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.highcharts-figure {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

If the chart height is set to a percentage, it resizes "badly":

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
        height: '100%', // set it to a fixed size and the chart will behave well but won't fill the entire height
      margin:0
    },
```

The chart should fill the page and not overflow it. I didn't find any way of doing it sort of setting a fixed height to the chart and, possibly, listening to resize events.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `vh` units:

```
#container {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yudsaL8n/

**API Reference**: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.height

Comment: I had tried this too, but in combination with other markup and it didn't work. Seeing your minimum markup was illuminating! Now I could see my mistakes! Thank you. Worked like a charm.